# Eclipse m2e Maven Compile Error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When trying to import a maven project into Eclipse it would tell me that there are compile errors:

[image]

Note that I can't share the project but it worked **flawlessly** before.

What could be the problem? Did my installation of m2e break?

Even after uninstalling all software that has to do with m2e maven import is still available.

I use [this](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2-with-java8-patches) version.

Comment: Have you installed the Java 8 patch for Eclipse AND for m2e?

Comment: These are not compile errors, but M2E complaining that it cannot handle that plugin. I would have expected it to easily understand what to do with compilation stuff, but maybe it always needs first to download a specific plugin connector, even for such basic tasks.

Comment: @Thomas Uhrig: I only downloaded the Eclipse Java 8 patched version, it already included a m2e installation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [maven from the command line](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) to download dependencies and then importing the project solved the problem. Not ideal but works.